# Convert date string ddmmyy to dd/mm/yyyy in angular ng datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, angular9

Am using `NgbDatePicker` the problem is whenever user clicks on the toggle and select the date means it converts required format `dd/mm/yyyy` at the same time instead of picking user enters the date as string like `ddmmyyyy` it does not convert to `dd/mm/yyyy` (Eg: 10072020 to 10/07/2020)the split is not working as expected in `CustomDateParserFormatter`. Kindly help me how to solve this issue and i don't know how to proceed.
*component.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter {
    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (!value) {
            return null;
        }
        const parts = value;
        parts.split('/');
        console.log("first calling");
        return { year: +parts[0], month: +parts[1], day: +parts[2] } as NgbDateStruct;

    }
    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-template
        console.log("second calling");
        return date ? ('0' + date.day).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + date.month).slice(-2) + '/' + date.year : null;
    }
}
```

*component.html*

```
<div class="input-group datePicker">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" ngbDatepicker formControlName="dateofBrith"
        [minDate]="{year: 1945, month: 1, day: 1}" [maxDate]="{year: 2020, month: 12, day: 31}"
        name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (ngModelChange)="changeDob($event)"
        maxlength="10">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn calendar btn-custom btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()"
            type="button"><img src="/assets/images/dateicon.png"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In console.log ("firstcalling") string split is not working when the user enters the value directly it should convert to `dd/mm/yyyy`. Can you guys help me how to convert the date string `ddmmyyyy` to date format `dd/mm/yyy`.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should change code

```
const parts = value;
parts.split('/');
```

to this

```
const parts = value.split('/');
```

Also you need to check after spliting it. below condition check if it contain / i.e.
If entered manually or not.

```
if(parts.length === 3) {
  return { year: +parts[0], month: +parts[1], day: +parts[2] } as NgbDateStruct;
}
else {
  return { year: +value.substring(0,2), month: +value.substring(2,4), day: 
           + value.substring(4,8) } as NgbDateStruct;
}
```

Comment: @santhoskadam but format not changing with dd/mm/yyyyy